# Updating a value in Data.ByteString

Tags: haskell, bytestring

The C language provides a very handy way of updating the `nth` element of an array: `array[n] = new_value`. My understanding of the `Data.ByteString` type is that it provides a very similar functionality to a C array of `uint8_t` - access via `index :: ByteString -> Int -> Word8`. It appears that the opposite operation - updating a value - is not that easy.

My initial approach was to use the `take`, `drop` and `singleton` functions, `concat`etaned in the following way:

```
updateValue :: ByteString -> Int -> Word8 -> ByteString
updateValue bs n value = concat [take (n-1) bs, singleton value, drop (n+1) bs]
```

(this is a very naive implementation as it does not handle edge cases)

Coming with a C background, it feels a *bit* too heavyweight to call 4 functions to update one value. Theoretically, the operation complexity is not that bad:

- `take` is O(1)
- `drop` is O(1)
- `singleton` is O(1)
- `concat` is O(n), but here I am not sure if the *n* is the length of the concatenated list altogether or if its just, in our case, 3.

My second approach was to ask Hoogle for a function with a similar type signature: `ByteString -> Int -> a -> ByteString`, but nothing appropriate appeared.

Am I missing something very obvious, or is really that complex to update the value?

I would like to note that I understand the fact that the `ByteString` is immutable and that changing any of its elements will result into a new `ByteString` instance.

EDIT:
A possible solution that I found while reading about the `Control.Lens` library uses the `set` lens. The following is an outtake from GHCi with omitted module names:

```
> import Data.ByteString
> import Control.Lens
> let clock = pack [116, 105, 99, 107]
> clock
"tick"
> let clock2 = clock & ix 1 .~ 111
> clock2
"tock"
```

Comment: Depends on what your end goal is. If you really want to read a file in, modify one byte, and write it out again, this approach seems reasonable. If what you're actually trying to do is modify every single byte, but one byte at a time, you probably want `map`. Can you explain a bit more about what you're ultimately after?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I get your point. I am trying to build a *very* small virtual machine and I am using `ByteString` as the backing memory storage. The size in question is in order of tens of bytes. An instruction comes in and executing it modifies a specific memory byte, e.g. `mov 4, mem7` (and that is where our `updateValue` function comes in). Therefore, `map`ping is not an option here. What might be an important addition is that performance is a valid concern in this case.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to convert the `ByteString` to a `Storable` `Vector`, then modify that:

```
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Data.Vector.Storable (modify)
import Data.Vector.Storable.ByteString  -- provided by the "spool" package
import Data.Vector.Storable.Mutable (write)
import Data.Word (Word8)

updateAt :: Int -> Word8 -> ByteString -> ByteString
updateAt n x s = vectorToByteString . modify inner . byteStringToVector
  where
    inner v = write v n x
```

See the documentation for [`spool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/spool-0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Storable-ByteString.html) and [`vector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Storable.html#g:18).

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this uses 4 separate functions, two of which are just the conversion. Do you think that `Data.Vector` could be a feasible replacement for `Data.ByteString` in this case? (In order to get rid of the two conversions)

Comment: @DanielLovasko I absolutely think replacing `ByteString` with a mutable structure is appropriate here. I would go even farther than using `Vector` to use e.g. `STArray` and lift your virtual machine stepping operation into `ST`. Moving from repeated O(n) update to O(1) is a no-brainer when performance matters.

Comment: @DanielWagner I never heard of the `ST` monad before, but it totally makes sense to use it here. For anyone reading this, I highly recommend the IRC logs in the beginning of [this page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad/ST).